# reload tableview on tabbarview controller with viewcontroller.m file

Tags: ios, tableview

My question is basically about how to update tableview controller on `tabbarcontroller` (3rd item). I am working on storyboard. there is a `tabbarcontroller` and 4 viewcontrollers connected to it. The first `viewcontainer` has segmented control which has two different tableviews. It is working perfectly no problem at all. I need to add similar tableviews to 3. and 4. view controllers also. I added delegate, data source and referencing outlet but it is not working. I used

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
```

for first view and called `[table reloadData]` from `viewDidLoad`. I don't know why same table from different view controller can not be called. How can I solve this issue, any suggestions please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW all view controllers which is connected to tabviewcontroller has same class viewcontroller...

Answer (score 0):

you can take a reference of the controller with the table from the tabbarcontroller and then reload your table. If I were you I would just put `[table reloadData];` in my `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` function.

Comment: I moved [table reloadData]; to viewWillAppear function and add if case to check if the table is the one that I want.
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
      if (tableView == videoTable) {
It is working and turns true for if clause but still table is empty... I use object to fill cell like addsubview object.photo but it is not working.

Comment: This is a different problem. You either don't have content, or you don't create the cells in the right way. With reload in viewWillAppear the table reloads every time you see the viewcontroller.

Comment: I have content because when I add breakpoints I can see that the object is willed in with RSS. I checked the cell and it is not nil so I guess it is created in the right way. Here is the question. Is it possible to use one cellForRowAtIndexPath function for more than one tableview in storyboard? As I mentioned before this tabelviews are on different viewcontrollers...